# I bought a domain name. Now, how do I set up a mail server? (IMAP)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix, email

Please, give me the **best**, easiest-to-understand tutorial for a beginner setting up a mail server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You bought a domain? Through which reseller? They usually provide you with mail server configuration. If you don't have these services available - I can recommend creating a Google Apps account. Then update your DNS MX records to those of Google Apps and you're able to use (and manage) mail accounts for your domain through Gmail (which offers excellent spam filtering).

Google Apps: http://www.google.com/apps/

Comment: If you actually own the server, as I assume since you're listing Ubuntu as OS, take a look at "howtoforge" tutorials, specifically those referencing the "perfect setup". Installation and configuration of mail services is available somewhere in the guide.

http://www.howtoforge.com/perfect_setup_ubuntu_6.06 (don't mind the version number, steps are quite the same)

Comment: +1 for using google apps or any other 3rd party mail service. Setting up a mail server is not for the faint of heart, nor a beginner.